# Manga/Novel about an injured blacksmith playing a Virtual Reality MMORPG

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga

I remember reading a book about an above 50ish blacksmith (with an English sounding name) who got injured so as a way to get through it he ends up playing a Virtual Reality MMORPG.

One defining factor I remember is that his kids (3) comes over with his grandkid for spring break. He ended having some problem with his daughter’s husband over staying longer and if I remember right he ends up fighting the guy. Also, he owned a cellar full of expensive wine.

Comment: Was he a blacksmith before he started playing VR? Were there a lot of statistics screens showing his progress? And did he find some sort of exploit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible match is *[Spending My Retirement in a Game](https://readnovelfull.com/spending-my-retirement-in-a-game.html)* by Dicevr.

[image: Cover of Spending my Retirement in a Game]

> Follow Benjamin Joyce, an elderly man with a passion for blacksmithing who spent his life travelling the world and learning new things. Now, after helping out the developers of the first ever real VRMMO game, he gets the chance to play said game earlier than the majority of other people.
>
> Taking this chance to do what he loves now that his real body is slowly giving in to his old age and the profession he lives for is no longer as important as it used to be, he starts his journey to become this new world's greatest Craftsman!

The injury:

> As a chain reaction, the metal fell on top of some tools laying on a table near Benjamin, flinging them right into the opening to the hot coal-filled forge. Of course, as one might expect, some of the burning coals were thrown out of the opening through the impact, directly onto Benjamin's right arm, melting into his flesh.

....

> He had multiple surgeries after that, trying to save as much of his arm as possible. Luckily, it didn't have to be amputated, but there was still a lot of damage done to the muscles and bones in Benjamin's arm. The surgeon that worked on Benjamin did an amazing job, but even so, he had to give up his passion for most of his craftsmanship.

I haven't found mention of "spring break" yet, but he does have a grandchild.

Answer (score 3):

This might be Jared Mandani's *[True Smithing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089QQW6VZ)*

[image: Front cover of True Smithing]

> Angus Bjornson only ever wanted to do one thing: to continue crafting exquisite weapons and pieces of armor for his loyal customers. Unfortunately, after one accident too many that leaves the old blacksmith completely disabled, it would seem he has no other choice but to hang up his hammer.
>
> However, that would be underestimating the stubbornness of the self-made man. Fearing he’s not going to stop until he ends up dead in his forge, Angus’ children offer him a virtual rig that connects to Imperium Games’ many universes.
>
> After choosing a fantasy-based world called Alterwelt, Angus—now known as Hephaestus—quickly learns that he can make use of his lifetime of experience by disabling the Auto function and playing on Manual. His skills allow him to create unique items that beat everything sold on the market. But Hephaestus has a long way to go before he can afford his own in-game forge. Moreover, he only ever learned to work with steel while here he has access to metals as strange and exotic as azuraneum, veridium, orichalcum…
>
> Still, that might be the least of his problems. After he’s made a few sales and starts to get some recognition, Hephaestus realizes that there’s a reason the market is oversaturated with crappy items. As it turns out, a greedy guild enforces a monopoly on the crafting and they’re ready to do anything to keep anyone—lest of all a lone blacksmith—from digging into their profits…

Found with a search for `litrpg blacksmith`

Comment: It isn’t but I’ll sure as hell read it. The one I’m thinking of his kid arm’s involved intill they come over for spring break

Comment: @Turcotte: 
What do you mean my "his kid's arm"? :) If this made you think of additional details, you can [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Sorry, meant aren’t not arm